# Lifetime of a mutable reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am learning borrowing concepts in rust. So, here I found something uncomprehensive.

```
struct A(i32);

fn main() {
    let mut x = A(5);
    let z;
    // first block
    {
        let t = &mut x;
        z = &t.0;
    }
    let p = &x;
    println!("{}", p.0);
    println!("{}", z)
}
```

I am getting below error

```
   |
22 |         let t = &mut x;
   |                 ------ mutable borrow occurs here
...
26 |     let p = &x;
   |             ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
27 |     println!("{}", p.0);
28 |     println!("{}", z)
   |                    - mutable borrow later used here
```

I assume that after the first block, variable t goes out of scope. Also z is taken as immutable reference. Then. why rust is treating z as a mutable reference or is 't' still alive till last line?
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `&t.0` is a reborrow of `z`, which means that its (implicit, here) lifetime is (at most) the same as the lifetime of the exlusive borrow. This means that, while it is a shared borrow, for the Rust borrow checker, the same rules than exclusive borrow applied, *because there is an other exclusive borrow that is still alive*.

If, instead of borrowing `x` *through `t`*, you borrow `x` directly, the problem disappears:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = A(5);
    let z;
    // first block
    {
        let t = &mut x;
        z = &x.0;
    }
    let p = &x;
    println!("{}", p.0);
    println!("{}", z)
}
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f523f93491aae445fa7ff35237af9e6d).

Unfortunately, the documentation for reborrowing is AFAIK quite sparse, so I've tried to aggregate a few relevant links.

You can have more details about the exact constraints the borrow checker takes into account with reborrowing in [the reference](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#reborrow-constraints).

You have already posted [a link](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) to a counterexample of why it is not safe for reborrowing not to extend the lifetime of the exclusive borrow, even though you only hold a shared borrow in the end.

If you want more background information on Rust's memory model for reborrowing, you can read the [Stacked Borrows paper](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/rustbelt/stacked-borrows/). In short, even though the behavior of the previous example can be surprising because `&x.0` and `&t.0` *have exactly the same value at runtime*, they cannot be exchanged one for the other, because pointers carry more information than just an address (see [this article](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2022/04/11/provenance-exposed.html) for an explanation about that).

Answer (score -2):

Though z isn't a mutable borrow, the variable t mutably borrows the variable x in another block, such that it is moved. While this could be sensible code, the limitations of the borrow-checker for it to be computable makes it so that it must refuse the borrowing of p, since the variable has already been moved into another variable, that is t, which takes ownership of the variable by mutably borrowing it.

For exemple, even this simple code, which to rust's borrow-checker is equivalent will give a similar error while compiling:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: i32 = 5;
    let t = &mut x;
    let p = &x;
    println!("{}", p);
    println!("{}", t);
}
```

Will give the following output:

```
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
4 |     let t = &mut x;
  |             ------ mutable borrow occurs here
5 |     let p = &x;
  |             ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
6 |     println!("{}", p);
7 |     println!("{}", t);
  |                    - mutable borrow later used here
```

TLDR; If you move a variable in one scope, or mutably borrow it, you can't borrow it later on.

Comment: Your example is different from mine. In your example, it is very evident how the borrow checker is just playing its role in the sense you can't have a mutable and immutable borrow at the same time.

Comment: I know the code is quite different, but it's not to the borrow checker. The thing is, the borrow checker doesn't understand what your code is trying to achieve, it just has a set of rules to respect, and in that sense, it applies essentially the same rules of borrowship in that simpler example. While in the end your exemple looks like it has two immutable borrows, for the borrow checker, you tried having a borrow of some sort after having a mutable borrow, even if you usde your mutable borrow to make another immutable borrow.

Comment: This answer is false. Not only `x` is never moved in neither your example nor the OP's example, but the reason these two examples do not compile is not the same. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Not to mention that mutably borrowing a variable at one point does not prevent you from borrowing later on...

Comment: @jthulhu though you are right, it's, at least to my understanding, that the borrow is "consumed" by the other variable, but your answer is much better than mine, in terms of details, I think I both missed the point, and didn't formulate my answer correctly.

Comment: I think the main concept that was missing from your answer is the one of reborrow, but it's understandable as it's very poorly documented (which is surprising, as Rust has a very good documentation usually).